# Start Sublime 3 from terminal, when default is Sublime Text 2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sublimetext2

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Calling `sublime foo.txt` would normally open `foo.txt` in Sublime Text 2. Recently I installed [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-public-beta). In addition to this, I tried to remove Sublime Text 2 completely from my filesystem.

After doing this, my system still tries to open Sublime Text 2 when I use `sublime` in my terminal. Clearly this is no good - because I removed Sublime Text 2. (at least partially).
I noticed the Sublime Text 2 icon is still in my applications list. If I try to remove it by clicking `Uninstall` I get the following error:

`The files which should be removed are not part of any installed software.`

So how do I fully remove it from an Ubuntu system, and how do I make `sublime` open Sublime Text 3?

Comment: Can you check where sublime you use by typing command `which sublime`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `sublime`, your computer should run a bash file at */usr/bin/sublime*  (running `which sublime` as Mike Li suggested will confirm the location.  Open that up and edit it for Sublime Text 3.  The contents of that file should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/lib/sublime-text-2/sublime_text --class=sublime-text-2 "$@"
```

Edit it as so: (On my computer the executable is called subime_text_3 instead of subime_text.  Verifiy by opening */usr/lib/sublime-text-3*.)

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/lib/sublime-text-3/sublime_text_3 --class=sublime-text-3 "$@"
```

Point it to the location of Sublime Text 3 on your system.

**Edit** Build 2221 (using the [ppa](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/sublime)) changed the installation directory from /usr/lib/sublime-text-2 to /opt/sublime_text_2

Comment: Great - this worked. Also, this isn't a solution to this problem but by default, the call to open Sublime Text 3 is `subl`.

Comment: Similarly to the *sublime* bash file, there is a *subl* bash file.  It seems that when you installed ST3, this bash file was created.  I had to make that file manually for ST2 (by copying the *sublime-text* bash file).

Answer (score 26):

Type : **subl**  in terminal to launch Sublime Text 3 from terminal.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: ```/usr/bin/subl``` is shell script which is running ```/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text```

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to do extra configuration for this. Just use `subl` commnad and it will open the sublime text editor.

Comment: For me it works on Ubuntu 16 using the last Sublime Text Build 3176.

Answer (score 0):

For sublimetext 3, it is only need "subl"